# Button not working as expected on click in react

Tags: reactjs, button, onclick, create-react-app

```
import React from 'react'

const Support = () => {
  
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={()=>console.log('support')}>add</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

this is the simple button , which is not logging on onclick .

i tried , adding button in various component and tried clicking , its not working .

Comment: Based on the code you provided, the button seems to be correct. I guess issue lies somewhere else.

Comment: im aslo not sure where im going wrong, i have published in my [repo](https://github.com/Ramesh136/ctrlb-dashboard)  check out if you have time to spare

Comment: I have fixed this issue by removing one keyword from CSS, check my below answer and mark it accepted, if it will resolved your issue. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for your time on checking out , helped me solve this and dedug the cause , wasnt able to upvote because im new and dont have enough reputations .

Comment: You're welcome, Let me know if you have anything onto this, Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After debugging your code, I have found out issue on CSS side, Here, is the solution for the same.

remove `fixed` keyword from this `div` in `Home.js` component to make it work...

**=> Replace this....**

```
<div className="fixed inset-y-0 z-50 h-full w-64 flex-col">
  <SideBar />
</div>;
```

**=> To this....**

```
<div className="inset-y-0 z-50 h-full w-64 flex-col">
  <SideBar />
</div>;
```

After this changes, Your **`Home.js`** component will look like this:

```
import { useState } from "react";
// import Login from "./components/Login";
import SideBar from "./SideBar";
import { Outlet, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

import { history } from "../utils/helper";
import Login from "./Login";

function Home() {
  const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false);
  history.navigation = useNavigate();

  return !isLoggedIn ? (
    <Login setIsLoggedIn={setIsLoggedIn} />
  ) : (
    <div className="flex">
      <div className="inset-y-0 z-50 h-full w-64 flex-col">
        <SideBar />
      </div>
      <div className="relative ml-40 p-2">
        <Outlet />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

I don't know what's the main cause behind this, But this **`fixed`** keyword is not allowing us to clicking on button, You can check into this in more detailed way according to your CSS styling.

Let me know, If you've any questions.

Comment: this really solved the issue , upon researching for cause of it , i found out that ,  the z-index property "z-50" was causing this issue , since its width is till w-64 , it was over the top of the button being rendered , this can be solved by removing z-index , or making width to auto , so that it does not overlay on any of the elements , thankl you so much for the help , really apperciate you time and quick help.